# getting vcpkg to build only release version

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to build only the release version of packages because creating debug versions takes too long / too much space. Vcpkg docs state that:

> Adding set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release) in a triplet: will cause most
> ports to only build release

In terminal when I run `set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)` I get

```
syntax error near unexpected token 'VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to set it in your triplet file. Make a copy and rename one of those default triplet files, say "x64-windows.cmake" to "x64-windows-rel.cmake". Then add a line so that:

```
 
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)
```

I think this will work on some libraries but not all, as it requires the libraries' own build files (CMakeLists.txt) to deal with it.

Comment: Could it also be set on the command prompt before running vcpkg.exe?  `set VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE=release`?

Comment: I don't think so. A quick search in vcpkg seems to suggest it doesn't check VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE in environment variable.

Comment: Looks like VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE is not well supported.  E.g., OpenCV's build fails if you set it since parts of the build scripts expect both release and debug are being built.

Comment: What if I want to let system detect triplet itself, and set only VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE?